# Hide a field in landscape mode

Tags: android, xamarin

Have any method to hide a field in landscape mode? 
Basically, I want:

```
android:visibility="GONE"
```

Just in landscape mode. Is possible? With a simple solution...

I tried this:

```
 public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
        {
// 1
        }
        else
        {
  // 2
        }

    }
```

But does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
  View my_view = findViewById(R.id.your_view);
  my_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I would do that in the `onCreate()` method of your Activity.

Comment: Got it! In my case, I'm programming in CSharp, I'll see what I can do. Thanks

Comment: Great answer.  I don't think it's necessary but do you think it may be a good extra measure of safety to make sure it sets to visible again if we rotate back to portrait?

Comment: @RhinoFeeder In Java's case it's not necessary (it might be done just for for safety, though) because everytime a runtime configuration change happens, `onCreate()` is called (if you are not forcing to not to do). I have no idea what's the C#'s case, though, so in that case I'd follow @elenasys' answer. And @user2191766, once your problem is solved, both for feedback and reputation purposes, don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most so other users may find it useful too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I see you are using Xamarin with C#, try to be more specific with your questions, so we can help you =).

This is an example of how to hide and unhide a button?

```
// get the initial orientation
var surfaceOrientation = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;

if (surfaceOrientation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0 || surfaceOrientation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180) {
    button.Visibility=ViewStates.Invisible;  
 } else {
    button.Visibility=ViewStates.Visible;
 }
```

or

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged (Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
  {
    base.OnConfigurationChanged (newConfig);                            
    if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape) {
      button.Visibility=ViewStates.Invisible;        //invisible in landscape.
    } else if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait) {
      button.Visibility=ViewStates.Visible;         //viible in portrait.
    }
```